# photos won't appear ? on vs code 1.69 win 7

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, windows-7-x64

[[screensht on vs and on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAQEG.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOLD0.jpg)
what is happening ?

i doing it right and then this happend can someone explain and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your index.html is inside the same directory as your image, you should remove the forward slash / and just have the image as such:

```
<img src="yourImageFileName.png" alt"your alt">
```

if the image is inside of a child directory to the parent directory that the index.html is inside of then it would be as such:

```
<img src="child/yourImageFileName.png" alt"your alt">
```